# How to convert each row of dataframe to 2D?

Tags: python, dataframe, 2d

I have my dataset as .csv and I open that using the pandas in python. Now I have dataframe of size (3259X37). I separate the label so that my feature dataframe becomes 3259x36 size and label dataframe becomes 3259x1 size. I need to convert each row of my feature dataframe to 2D such that I will have 3259 2D data each of size (mxn)[may be 4x9] such that each row containing 2D data corresponds to equivalent label in my label dataframe of size 3259x1. How can I do this please explain?

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to small example? You can then edit your question and put sample (small) input and expected output there. Without it is hard to answer it for others...

Comment: Hey @Sjn, please add examples of the different inputs and outputs that you expect so that we can understand your question better.